# Set background of Python OpenCV warpPerspective

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

When using `warpPerspective` to scale the image to be smaller, there are black area around it. It may be like:

[image]

or

[image]

How to make the black borders to be white?

```
pts1 = np.float32([[minx,miny],[maxx,miny],[minx,maxy],[maxx,maxy]])
pts2 = np.float32([[minx + 20, miny + 20,
                   [maxx - 20, miny - 20],
                   [minx - 20, maxy + 20],
                   [maxx + 20, maxy + 20]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(dst, M, (width, height))
```

How to remove the black borders after `warpPerspective`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the `warpPerspective` function from the online OpenCV documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html) says that there is a parameter you can give to the function to specify the constant border color:

```
cv2.warpPerspective(src, M, dsize[, dst[, flags[, borderMode[, borderValue]]]])
```

where

```
src – input image.
dst – output image that has the size dsize and the same type as src .
M – 3\times 3 transformation matrix.
dsize – size of the output image.
flags – combination of interpolation methods (INTER_LINEAR or INTER_NEAREST) and the optional flag WARP_INVERSE_MAP, that sets M as the inverse transformation ( \texttt{dst}\rightarrow\texttt{src} ).
borderMode – pixel extrapolation method (BORDER_CONSTANT or BORDER_REPLICATE).
borderValue – value used in case of a constant border; by default, it equals 0.
```

So something like:

```
cv2.warpPerspective(dist, M, (width, height), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 255)
```

Should change the border to a constant white color.

Comment: For white you need at the end ``... cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 255, 255, 255)``

Comment: I would say it should be: `cv2.warpPerspective(dist, M, (width, height), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderValue=(255, 255, 255))`

Answer (score 15):

While it is not listed in the documentation as a possible borderMode, you can also set borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT and it will not create any border whatsoever. It will keep the unchanged pixel settings of the destination image. In this manner you could make the border white or the border an image of your choice.

For example for image with a white border:

```
white_image = np.zeros(dsize, np.uint8)

white_image[:,:,:] = 255

cv2.warpPerspective(src, M, dsize, white_image, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)
```

Will create a white border for transformed image. In addition to the border you can also load anything as background image as long as it is the same size as the destination. For example, if I had a background panorama that I was warping an image onto I could use the panorama as the background.

Panorama with the warped image overlayed:

```
panorama = cv2.imread("my_panorama.jpg")

cv2.warpPerspective(src, M, panorama.shape, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)
```

Comment: This is awesome - I'm sure it used to be necessary to draw it on black and then use a transformed mask to transplant it. This is way cleaner.

Comment: Isn't this missing the `dst` parameter?  And the documentation says `dsize`, not shape.

Comment: @Trevor so with this, where the warped image now overlaps the background panorama, it's going to keep the background and not overlay the warped image pixels?  The call to `cv2.warpPerspective()` looks like it's missing the `dst`.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer no longer works. Try this to fill the exposed area with white.

```
outImg = cv2.warpPerspective(img, tr, (imgWidth, imgHeight), 
    borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
    borderValue=(255, 255, 255))
```

Comment: Can confirm. `borderMode` has to be passed as a named parameter now, otherwise it's ignored silently